# Install Maven jar with pom into local repository

Tags: maven

I have an old jar (`jsf-api-2.0.2.jar`). In this jar there is a `/META-INF/maven`-Folder.

How do I install the jar into my local repository?

`install:install-file` says I need to specify the artifactId myself. How do I force it to use the information in `jsf-api-2.0.2.jar!\META-INF\maven\com.sun.faces\jsf-api\pom.xml`?

Output:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jsf-api-2.0.2.jar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.410s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Feb 01 12:52:34 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/368M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default cli) on project standalone-pom: The artifact information is incomplete or not valid:
[ERROR] [0]  'groupId' is missing.
[ERROR] [1]  'artifactId' is missing.
[ERROR] [2]  'packaging' is missing.
[ERROR] [3]  'version' is missing.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: version is apache-maven-3.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/custom-pom-installation.html
Just ensure you're using at least version 2.5, which introduced this feature.

And by the way: the goal is `install-file`, not install-jar

Comment: Plugin 2.5 has not yet introduced in latest 3.1.1

Comment: Maven doesn't automatically selects the latest released version, but has predefined versions for common plugins, and 3.1.1 probably still uses maven-install-plugin-2.4. It's not so hard to force another version.

Comment: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.1:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>`

Comment: Too bad, plugin only install the first artifact whearat `richfaces-ui-3.3.0.GA.jar` contains multiple artifacts.

Comment: @RobertScholte's comment worked! Latest release of maven-install-plugin is now 2.5.2, FYI.